# MYSQL 2 SELECTS with group by

Tags: mysql

This should be the result:
[image]

And this is what I have to try:

```
SELECT ort Ort, (SELECT SUM(umsatz) FROM kunde WHERE geschlecht = "w") Frau,
(SELECT ort, SUM(umsatz) FROM kunde WHERE geschlecht = "m") Mann FROM kunde GROUP BY ort;
```

and it says me: `Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some sample data ?

Comment: You should provide some sample data and maybe translate the column headers to english, so that everyone can understand, what this is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to get revenue (`umsatz`) per location (`ort`) per gender (`geschlecht`).

If this is the case, then you need to use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT ort, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN geschlecht = "w" THEN umsatz ELSE 0 END) AS Frau,
       SUM(CASE WHEN geschlecht = "m" THEN umsatz ELSE 0 END) AS Mann
FROM kunde 
GROUP BY ort;
```

First `SUM` adds up all `geschlecht = "w"` records per `ort`, whereas second `SUM` adds up all `geschlecht = "m"` records per `ort`.